# Show "Viewport Overlays" panel for 3D viewport in a small area

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I have a small area of 3D viewport like this:

[image]

When I need to change its Viewport Overlays settings, I have to expand it:

[image]

It's very clumsy and kinda defeats the purpose of having a smaller 3D viewport. Can I, for example, call Viewport Overlays popup with a shortcut?

Comment: In Blender each header is "scrollable".

Comment: @p2or Well but I use a stylus... I don't have a scroll wheel.

Comment: I ended up configuring one of my stylus button as MMB and use it to scroll the header.

Comment: Configuring the stylus that way, is something you want to do anyway (required for a lot of other tools as well). Also please mention such details in your question, makes it less confusing to the reader why this is an issue at all...